# Resolve variable with embedded interpolated variable

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am using puppet 3.7.5. I have written a custom fact `php_v` which returns a version number.

Now I have a YAML file called `defaults.yaml` and this is working fine.

```
---
p_name: "php_v"
p_version: "%{::php_v}" # returns the custom fact
```

But I want something like this.

```
---
p_name: "php_v"
p_version: "%{::${p_name}}" 
# p_name should be replaced with "php_v"
# and custom fact should return the version
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: No, you cannot do this in Puppet/Hiera.

Comment: Now that we've gotten the X or your X/Y problem out of the way, you're welcome to present the Y.